# Irreducible polynomial over Dedekind domain remains irreducible in field of fractions

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $\mathcal{O}$ be a Dedekind domain, $K$ its field of fractions. Suppose $f\in \mathcal{O}[X]$ is irreducible. Is it irreducible in $K[X]$?

The motivation for my question is that this is true for UFD's, so it is natural to ask if it is still valid over an arbitrary Dedekind domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been answered pretty exhaustively by Pete Clark [on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/6651/counter-example-for-gausss-lemma-on-irreducible-polynomials). The upshot is that as soon as the class number is not 1, the result does not hold.